# Replace value one last valid item - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace a value in a column based off another column in a `pandas` df. Specifically, where `col B == X`, I want to change the value in `col C`, but for the last `X` in a given sequence. I can change all respective `X's` in `C`. But I only want to replace the last valid `X`. Would `mask` and last valid value be ideal here?

`X's` appear in random order and groupings

```
df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'A' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],             
    'B' : ['X','X','X','D','A','A','X','D'],                 
    'C' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],                
    })

df.loc[df['B'] == 'X', ['C']] = 'str'

mask = df['B'] == 'X'
```

Intended Output:

```
   A  B    C
0  1  X    1
1  1  X    1
2  1  X  str
3  1  D    1
4  1  A    1
5  1  A    1
6  1  X  str
7  1  D    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `shift` along with `numpy.where`

```
import numpy as np

b1 = df["B"].shift(-1) 
df["C"] = np.where((df["B"]=="X") & (b1!="X"), "str" , df["C"])
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   X   1
1   1   X   1
2   1   X   str
3   1   D   1
4   1   A   1
5   1   A   1
6   1   X   str
7   1   D   1
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR

```
mask = (df['B'] == 'X').astype(int)
mask = mask - mask.shift(-1)
df.loc[mask == 1, 'C'] = 'str'
df
Out[44]: 
   A  B    C
0  1  X    1
1  1  X    1
2  1  X  str
3  1  D    1
4  1  A    1
5  1  A    1
6  1  X  str
7  1  D    1
```

Explanation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'A' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],             
    'B' : ['X','X','X','D','A','A','X','D'],                 
    'C' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],                
    })
df
Out[35]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  X  1
1  1  X  1
2  1  X  1
3  1  D  1
4  1  A  1
5  1  A  1
6  1  X  1
7  1  D  1
```

Now you can have a mask where `df['B']=='X'`:

```
df['mask'] = (df['B'] == 'X').astype(int)
df
Out[37]: 
   A  B  C  mask
0  1  X  1     1
1  1  X  1     1
2  1  X  1     1
3  1  D  1     0
4  1  A  1     0
5  1  A  1     0
6  1  X  1     1
7  1  D  1     0
```

and in order to find the rows to replace you can do:

```
df['mask'] = df['mask'] - df['mask'].shift(-1)
df
Out[39]: 
   A  B  C  mask
0  1  X  1   0.0
1  1  X  1   0.0
2  1  X  1   1.0
3  1  D  1   0.0
4  1  A  1   0.0
5  1  A  1  -1.0
6  1  X  1   1.0
7  1  D  1   NaN
```

and at the end:

```
df.loc[df['mask'] == 1, 'C'] = 'str' 
df
Out[41]: 
   A  B    C  mask
0  1  X    1   0.0
1  1  X    1   0.0
2  1  X  str   1.0
3  1  D    1   0.0
4  1  A    1   0.0
5  1  A    1  -1.0
6  1  X  str   1.0
7  1  D    1   NaN
```